# How do I melee with Boba Fett?

Tags: xbox-one, star-wars-battlefront-2015

When I'm Boba Fett, I keep getting killed by people who come up to me and popping a personal shield and then meleeing me and taking a lot of health, how do I melee back? I realize I could use the flamethrower, but I like to keep it charged for use against heros and large groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, as Boba Fett, you can't melee. Because his left trigger makes him use his jetpack, pushing in on the right stick, which usually causes the character to melee, has him zoom in making him useful as a sniper character. But unfortunately you can't melee with him.